# Integral of two iid variables

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be real iid random variables, $S_n := \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ the sum of them and $\sigma(S_n)$ the generated sigma-algebra of $S_n$. How to show, that 
$\int_A X_1 = \int_A X_k$
is true for all $1 \leq k \leq n$ and every $A \in \sigma(S_n)$?

Answer (score 2):

1. Rewrite $S_n$ as the sum of $X_k, X_{k+1},\dots,X_n, X_1,\dots,X_{k-1}$, in this order, with the obvious changes if $k=n$ or $k=1$. Writing the sum this way, it is clear that the joint distribution of $X_1$ and $S_n$ is identical to the joint distribution of $X_k$ and $S_n$.
2. Therefore 
   $E [ f(X_1,S_n)  ]= E [f (X_k,S_n)]$, and in particular, letting $f (x,y) = x {\bf 1}_B(y)$, for a Borel set $B$, we have $E[X_1,S_n \in B] = E [X_k,S_n \in B]$.
3. Finally ${\cal G} = \{S_n \in B: B \mbox{ Borel in }\mathbb R\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Since every $\sigma$-algebra with respect to which $S_n$ is measurable must contain ${\cal G}$, it follows that ${\cal G} = \sigma(S_n)$.